# "During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred"

Tags: python-3.x, exception, try-catch

I am reading from a file a list of fractions, and parsing them into a list of tuples. I want an error to occur if the file is empty or if the denominator is less than or equal to 0.

I've tried putting `if(EOFERRor)`, `elif(zerodivisionerror)`, `elif(assertionerror)`, `else`.. inside the `InvalidFile(Exception)` class. Before my exception would raise for the end of the file read, so that's why I included that into it specifically.

My guess would be that EOF occurs at the same time as divide by zero, but I separated the list from the file to keep that from happening

```
class InvalidFile(Exception):

    if(EOFError):
        pass
    else:
        print('Invalid file format')
        sys.exit(1)

def createFractionList(filePath):    
    try:
        f = open(inFile)
        f.close()
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print('FileNotFoundError')
        sys.exit(1)

    fractionList = []
    for line in open(filePath):
        line = line.rstrip()
        try:
            numerator, denominator = tuple(int(x) for x in line.split())
        except:
            raise InvalidFile
        fractionList.append((numerator, denominator))
    for lists in fractionList:
       try:
            lists[0]/lists[1]
       except:
           raise InvalidFile
    return fractionList

dateList = createFractionList(inFile)
print(dateList)
```

INPUT:

```
1 0

3 4

5 6

7 8

9 10

0 8

2 4

9 12

20 24

35 40

54 60
```

Expected Output:

```
Invalid file format
```

Actual Output:

```
C:\Users\Xavier\PycharmProjects\hw4\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/Xavier/PycharmProjects/hw4/hw4.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Xavier/PycharmProjects/hw4/hw4.py", line 33, in createFractionList
    lists[1]/0
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```

Comment: how are you calling code? and `except:` is bad practice; you should e.g. `except ValueError:` or whatever exception(s) you really want to catch.

Comment: may I ask you , why you do this "lists[1]/0" ?

Comment: @hiroprotagonist I previously had it as: 

assert 1 / denominator
except  AssertionError:

but i took it out because I wasnt sure if that was the cause.
I added how I called the code

Comment: @TonyJafar lists[1] / 0 is to reference the second value of the tuple created, which is the denominator.

Comment: so you meant to write `lists[1] / lists[0]` (or the other way round?)

Comment: exactly :) that should fix that I think

Comment: @hiroprotagonist  I made the change to list[0]/list[1] and the same error occurred :(

Comment: you have `1 0` in your dataset which will result in a `ZeroDivisionError`...

Comment: @hiroprotagonist right, which is what I intended to test. By making the exception, it should catch the error and print the Invalid file format from the class I made earlier. It doesn't go to the class, but it freaks out instead

Comment: aaah is see what you mean. that is not how exceptions work.  your static code in the class definition is exectued when the class is created only (and not when the excepion is raised). `bool(EOFError)` is `True` so nothing happens then.

Comment: @hiroprotagonist Oooh gotcha. So I should make multiple "excepts" each with its own conditions. Then have them all reference invalid file, except eof.

So in the class it should just be:
print(error message)
exit.

Comment: @hiroprotagonist 
try:
  num, denom ....
  assert num/denom > 0 
except eoferror:
except assertionerror:
except "empty file error?":

is there a way to get all those conditions from one class? 
I know empty file error doesnt exist, so how would I check for that if the class definition isnt used at execution?

Answer (score 0):

The body of your `InvalidFile` exception does nothing because it's only run at declaration. And in any case, `if EOFError` is always true, so nothing happens. What you should do is override the `__init__` method with a custom text. Personally I don't think you need a custom exception, you can just use in-built ones instead.

Your first error is `FileNotFoundError` which you'd be better off checking with `os.path.exists()`.

You should use a context manager when you open the file, then you don't need to worry about closing it.

You don't need to strip the line because `int('1  \n') already strips whitespace. But maybe the input file has blank lines, so we could keep this.

You don't need to loop through the file and then the lists, because if at any point, the denominator is less than or equal to 0 the error should be raised. There's no point delaying the error for later. And it seems there is no point doing the division either because you can work out in advance if it's going to fail.

So all in all, you could rewrite the code like this:

```
import os.path

def create_fraction_list(file_path):
  if not os.path.exists(file_path):
    raise FileNotFoundError(file_path)
  fraction_list = []
  with open(file_path) as f:
    for line in f:
      line = line.strip()
      if not line:
        # have a blank line
        continue
      numerator, denominator = (int(x) for x in line.split())
      if denominator <= 0:
        raise ValueError(f'Denominator less that or equal to 0: {numerator}/{denominator}')
      fraction_list.append((numerator, denominator))
  if not fraction_list:
    # it's empty
    raise ValueError(f'Input file has no valid lines: {file_path}')
  return fraction_list

if __name__ == '__main__':
  try:
    fraction_list = create_fraction_list(inFile)
    print(fraction_list)
  except (FileNotFoundError, ValueError):
    print('Invalid file format.')
    sys.exit(1)
```